# Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $f$ an endomorphism. How do I prove the following?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$$im(f^2)=im(f) \implies V = ker(f) + im(f)$$

What I tried:
take $v \in V$. Then $v = v - f(v) + f(v)$

$f(v) \in im(f)$ trivial. So i tried to show $v - f(v) \in ker(f)$.
$f(v - f(v)) = f(v)-f(f(v))$

and that's where I'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Anyway, you are pretty close. By assumption we have $f(v)=f(f(w))$ for some $w$. So now try to find a very similar decomposition of $v$ to the one you tried, but using $w$.

Comment: thanks, I got it!

Comment: Follow from the Rank-Nullity Theorem [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/520851/742).